# Bind to property of object

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, binding

I am currently developing a little musicplayer just for fun.
I was wondering if I can bind to a class named Track and access its propertys in XAML.

```
public class Track
{
    public string TitleName { get; set; }
    public BitmapImage Cover { get; set; }
}
```

Code can explain better than I can so here's my **pseudo code**:

```
<Grid>
   <Image Source="{Binding BindingName="CurrentTrack" PropertyName="Cover"}"/>
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding BindingName="CurrentTrack" PropertyName="Title"}"/>
</Grid>
```

Can I get something like this without using a Converter or sth like that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access a child property like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding CurrentTrack.TitleName}"/>
```

You must have bound your View to your ViewModel

Comment: I try it out :D give me a sec

Comment: Is your View bound to your ViewModel? Is the DataContext set?

Comment: My DataContext is set. Is the line you posted the only thing I need ? All other bindings work fine but the ones on the childproperties wont

Comment: I didn't call OnPropertyChanged -.- My bad ^^ thx for your help and the fast reply ^^

Comment: That was going to be my next suggestion ;) - Glad you figured it out!